# PostgreSQL: schema diff/patch tool

Tags: postgresql, schema

Consider the following setting:

- A production DB
- A dev db, on which schema changes are made to enable new features

When the development of a new feature is complete, I have to manually update the prod db schema until `pg_dump --schema-only` on both DBs is identical. This process is error prone and tedious.

So, I am looking for a tool that can:

- Show a summary of the differences between two schemas (like `diff`). Note that I am not looking for a mere textual diff of the schema, but a more elaborate tool that can draw conclusions like "Table `X` has a new column `Y`".
- Auto-generate the SQL code that would convert one schema to another (like [`patch`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_(Unix)))

**Is there a schema [diff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff)/[patch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_(Unix)) tool that can help me convert prod schemas to the more advanced dev schemas?**

Comment: Rather than doing a diff, you should manage your migration scripts in a controlled way. Never do ad-hoc DDL changes to a DBMS, always put the change into a script (which is stored in a version control system) and then apply the script. Look into tools like Liquibase or Flyway

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks. Even with this approach, a diff/patch tool would make my life easier. BTW, I can't help humming the song.

Comment: You might try pg_comparator: http://pgfoundry.org/projects/pg-comparator/ (I have never used it though). Liquibase has a built-in diff as well and emits the results as a Liquibase changeset if I'm not mistaken so that might be a good starting point for more a controlled schema management

Comment: Thanks. Care to post it as an answer so I can upvote?

Answer (score 12):

*Sorry to resurrect an old question*

Recently I have been using the <s>[0xDBE](https://www.jetbrains.com/dbe/)</s> [DataGrip](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/) Database management tool by JetBrains.

It supports multiple database engines, in the excellent Jetbrains IDE, and a key feature I have found useful is the ability to `diff` 2 tables (DEV and PROD).

Below is a screenshot of the diff in action (in this case there is only one column difference). The screenshot is the result of the "Merge Right" button at the top, generating the SQL required to bring the right table up to scratch.

[image: 0xDBE SQL Table Diff]

Hope this new tool helps.

Comment: There is no problem with resurrecting old questions (there are even badges to achieve from that).  And a question: is it possible to compare whole databases (I mean, at least, all tables in them)?

Comment: @dezso - Thanks for the reassurance. Yes you can compare at a database, schema and table level.

Comment: How does one initiate the diff feature in 0xDBE? I cannot find any menu item for a 'diff' tool.

Comment: @BasilBourque - From the left hand `Database` menu, select the 2 tables you want to compare (with `cmd/ctrl + click`), right click and select `Compare`

Comment: I've recently came across a new tool, written in python, [migra](https://github.com/djrobstep/migra). It can track changes to changes to tables, views, functions, indexes, constraints, enums, sequences, and installed extensions and can also be used as a library

Comment: @Ewan Also, migra tracks everything in both databases, including triggers and functions. But DataGrip doesn't. That's why, I discourage from using DataGrip as a diff tool. Drawbacks are also present: 1) migra is only a PostgreSQL tool; 2) migra does track changes, but doesn't always produce appropriate DDL operators, like alter table... add column, drop column instead of alter table... rename column etc. And I haven't found any tool, that produces correct DDL commands. They always need polishing. Also, without some migration tool, like Liquibase, any database modifications will be too complex.

Answer (score 6):

Use [liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/quickstart.html).

It supports [diff](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/diff.html), generating a db from scratch, patching a db, rolling back a db, and a bunch of other stuff.

You used to have to write everything in XML with liquibase, but not anymore. You can write 99% of it in the SQL dialect of your choosing. Example:

```
--liquibase formatted sql

--changeset neil:1 

create table contacts(
  contact_id serial primary key,
  name text not null unique
);

--changeset neil:2
alter table contacts add column phone_num text;
```

You should keep your liquibase changelogs in git or what-have-you.

Comment: An issue with this is that it doesn't get the ordering or removing constraints and primary keys right.

Comment: [Flyway](http://flywaydb.org) is another choice similar to Liquibase.